# Algorithms to compute the Wasserstein distance between two discrete probability measures.

Tags: optimization, algorithms, linear-programming, optimal-transport

Let $\mu$ & $\nu$ be a pair of discrete probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$ defined by

$$\mu = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{x_i} \quad ;\quad  \nu= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{y_i}$$

where $x_i, y_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$. We can think of $\mu$ and $\nu$ as denoting two distributions of $n$ shipping crates on $\mathbb{R}^d$ where crates have equal mass and can be stacked on top of one another. I want to find an algorithm to compute the Wasserstein distance between $\mu$ and $\nu$. The Wasserstein distance is given by

$$  W_p(\mu,\nu) = \min_{\sigma \in S_n} \left\{ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_{\sigma(i)} |^p  \right\}. \hskip20pt (*)$$

I.e. The Wasserstein distance gives the minimum cost necessary to move all crates from distribution $\mu$ to distribution $\nu$, where the cost for moving a crate from $x$ to $y$ in this case is $\frac{1}{n}|x - y|^p$. See e.g. Villani - Topics in Optimal Transport Theory, page 5.

The minimizer clearly exists because $S_n$ is finite, but (at least naively) it seems to be difficult to compute in practice because $|S_n| = n!$. Looking online I find some hints that the problem might be solvable in polynomial time, but I become stooped in complicated general theory which does not immediately seem to apply to this problem. I am not familiar with either optimal transport theory or optimization. I am most interested in the case $p=1$, though the cases $p\in(1,\infty)$ are also of interest.

Can anyone provide either:

(i) An account of existing theory/algorithms for computing (*), ideally in the case $p=1$ but also possibly for general $p\in[1,\infty)$, or

(ii) Some clear references covering (i).

Many thanks!
A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case this could be seen as an instance of the [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), which you can solve using the [Hungarian Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_method) in $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$.

Comment: Great :) I had not known about the assigment problem, so that is really helpful! One point that I observe though is that the assignment problem asks to find the optimal solution (i.e. the optimal $\sigma$, which may also be non-unique), whereas in my case I only need to find the optimal cost (which could in theory be known without knowledge of sigma). Thus, at least a priori, my problem seems simpler than the assignment problem. So one may even hope for faster algorithms that $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ in this case. Do you know of any work around this?

Comment: I’m not sure, but if your solution doesn’t need to be exact, you can look into approximations such as Entropy-Regularized Wasserstein Distance or if applicable to your problem Convolutional Wasserstein Distance, or others. See for example [Computational Optimal Transport](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00567) or [Solomon et al](https://people.csail.mit.edu/jsolomon/assets/convolutional_w2.compressed.pdf), and look at some pretty pictures too! :)

Comment: @Aerinmund Fagelson Pretty much the same question by me, and answer https://www.or-exchange.org/questions/12391/can-linear-assignment-problem-be-solved-faster-if-only-optimal-cost-is-needed-and-not-optimal-assignment . That forum is now read only. And has essentially moved to https://or.stackexchange.com/ , where you should feel free to ask again (linking to this Mathematics Stack Exxhange question).

Comment: Great! Thank-you dirich1337 and Mark L. Stone. Taken together that completely answers my question :)