# How is Optimal Transport algorithmically related to the Assignment Problem?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, optimization, optimal-transport

In **optimal transport**, we calculate the distance between two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ over the compact set $[a,b]\subset\mathbb R$, using the **Earth Movers distance** which is a special case of the Wasserstein formula:

$$W=\inf_\pi\int|x-y|\,{\rm d}\pi(x,y),$$

where $\pi$ is interpreted as a **transport matrix** satisfying $\int\pi(x,y)dy=\mu(x)$ and $\int\pi(y,x)dy=\nu(x)$.

It is said that the Earth Movers distance shown above is solved using the [Hungarian algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=munkres%20algorithm) by Munkres, which is also used for solving the **Assignment Problem**. Are optimal transport and the assignment problem related then, and how mathematically?

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660192/algorithms-to-compute-the-wasserstein-distance-between-two-discrete-probability

Comment: it begs the question of how Sinkhorn algorithm is different from Hungarian algorithm